# How can I get a String from a URL

Tags: php, android, html, http, inputstream

My application gets most of its data from a php web server.

My problem is when the server return errors.
The errors are not HTML pages, but simple strings.
for example:

```
ERROR001
```

could stand for invalid name.

here is my code:

```
String responseBody = null;
URL url = new URL(strUrl);
URLConnection connection;
connection = url.openConnection();
connection.setUseCaches(false);
InputStream isResponse = (InputStream) connection.getContent(); // on errors I get IOException here
responseBody = convertStreamToString (isResponse);
```

When I use it, I get IOException on  connection.getContent();

I also tried:

```
HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet(url);
String responseBody = null;
responseBody = mClient.execute(getMethod,mResponseHandler); // on errors I getClientProtocolException
```

but I get getClientProtocolException on mClient.execute

Any ideas how I could read a result like ERROR001 into a string?

Comment: I'm fairly unfamiliar with PHP, but have you checked the resposne code coming back from the server?  Generally, that's a reliable way to tell if you received a valid response or not.

Comment: This does not actually have anything to do with PHP. There is an exception being thrown and not being handled on the client side. try/catch is needed rather than attempting to interpret the bad response body.

Comment: I just noticed that when the response from the web page is "OK", I get no error. The exception occurs only when when the result is of the form "ERRORXXX"

Comment: I agree with Paul Sasik - add try/catch block and inside that block try to read your response.

Comment: When I try the URL on my PC browser, I get "ERRORXXX" and this is exactly what I would like to get on in my application. Instead, I get an exception. I would like to check it on the client side (my side) but I get the exception before I can read it.

Comment: have you tired the example I posted below?

Comment: I tried to surround with try/catch, but when the exception occurs, the response is null.
The problem is that the server response header is HTTP Error 500 (Internal server error) and this is what prevents me from reading the response content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that on error, the Http header is HTTP Error 500 (Internal server error).
To read the error content I used the following code:

```
    String responseBody = null;
    URL url = new URL(strUrl);
    HttpURLConnection connection;
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    InputStream isResponse = null;
    try {
        isResponse = connection.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        isResponse = connection.getErrorStream();
    }
    responseBody = convertStreamToString (isResponse);

    return responseBody;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
url = new URL(desiredUrl);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
```

Try this one. 
I think you are not calling the  connection.connect() method.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you use HttpClien?
you may want to try this:

```
String responseBody;

HttpGet request = new HttpGet("your url");
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(request);
HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

if(entity != null){
    responseBody = convertStreamToString (entity.getContent());
}
```